# how to read a excel file and insert data into oracle table

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, oracleforms, oracle-fusion-middleware

i am using oracle 11g.how to read a excel file and insert data into oracle table using plsql and oracle forms.i am new to to his topic.`enter code here`

i tried `https://sites.google.com/site/craigsoraclestuff/oracle-forms-webutil/read-excel-into-forms`

i need simple correct answer.

how to inser this part to the program  :

```
v_fName := WebUtil_File.File_Open_Dialog(
                  directory_name => 'C:\'
                  ,File_Filter => null
                  ,Title => 'Select Client filename to Open.'
            );
```

how to get cell value to a variable.i don't see it with this example.i have only one excel sheet.no need to check number of sheets.don't know how to customize all these things.

i need data from 4th column,5th column,5th column   and from 5th row i wat to match column 5th with another table and not matches assign flag variable "N" and if matches then flag variable "y" fro each row.

Answer (score 2):

A guy named [Anton Scheffer](https://technology.amis.nl/author/anton-scheffer/) wrote [this](https://technology.amis.nl/2013/01/19/read-a-excel-xlsx-with-plsql/) package that allow you to do querys into an excel file directly (once uploaded to the database of course):

```
select * from table( as_read_xlsx.read( as_read_xlsx.file2blob( 'DOC', 'Book1.xlsx' ) ) );

  SHEET_NR SHEET_NAME ROW_NR COL_NR CELL  CEL STRING_VAL NUMBER_VAL DATE_VAL
---------- ---------- ------ ------ ----- --- ---------- ---------- --------------------------
         1 Mijn naam       1      1 A1    N                      11
         1 Mijn naam       1      2 B1    N                      12
         1 Mijn naam       1      3 C1    N                      13
         1 Mijn naam       2      1 A2    N                      21
         1 Mijn naam       2      2 B2    N                      22
         1 Mijn naam       2      3 C2    N                      23
         1 Mijn naam       3      1 A3    N                      31
         1 Mijn naam       3      2 B3    N                      32
         1 Mijn naam       3      3 C3    N                      33
         1 Mijn naam       4      4 D4    S   D4
         1 Mijn naam       6      2 B6    D
         1 Mijn naam       7      2 B7    D
         1 Mijn naam       8      2 B8    D
         1 Mijn naam       9      2 B9    D
         1 Mijn naam      10      2 B10   D
         2 Sheet3          2      2 B2    S   Test
         2 Sheet3          3      3 C3    D                         19-JAN-2013 20:17:00
         2 Sheet3          4      1 A4    S   Anton
```

Some examples

```
// every sheet and every cell
    select * 
    from table( as_read_xlsx.read( as_read_xlsx.file2blob( 'DOC', 'Book1.xlsx') ) );

// cell A3 from the first and the second sheet
    select *
    from table( as_read_xlsx.read( as_read_xlsx.file2blob( 'DOC', 'Book1.xlsx' ), '1:2', 'A3' ) )

// every cell from the sheet with the name "Sheet3"
    select *
    from table( as_read_xlsx.read( as_read_xlsx.file2blob( 'DOC', 'Book1.xlsx' ), 'Sheet3' ) )
```

**So once you had your query results you can insert them as needed into your tables**

Here's the full package:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE package as_read_xlsx
is
/**********************************************
**
** Author: Anton Scheffer
** Date: 19-01-2013
** Website: http://technology.amis.nl/blog
**
** Changelog:
** 18-02-2013 - Ralph Bieber
                Handle cell type "str" to prevent ORA-06502
                if cell content is a string calculated by formula, 
                then cell type is "str" instead of "s" and value is inside <v> tag
** 19-02-2013 - Ralph Bieber
                Add column formula in tp_one_cell record, to show, if value is calculated by formula 
** 20-02-2013 - Anton Scheffer
                Handle cell types 'inlineStr' and 'e' to prevent ORA-06502
** 19-03-2013 - Anton Scheffer
                Support for formatted and empty strings
                Handle columns per row to prevent ORA-31186: Document contains too many nodes 
** 12-06-2013 - Anton Scheffer
                Handle sharedStrings.xml on older Oracle database versions
** 18-09-2013 - Anton Scheffer
                Fix for LPX-00200 could not convert from encoding UTF-8 to ...
                (Note, this is an error I can't reproduce myself, maybe depending on database version and characterset)
                Thank you Stanislav Safonov for this solution
                Handle numbers with scientific notation
** 20-01-2014 - Anton Scheffer
                Fix for a large number (60000+) of strings
** 16-05-2014 - Anton Scheffer
                round to 15 digits

******************************************************************************
******************************************************************************
Copyright (C) 2013 by Anton Scheffer

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
THE SOFTWARE.

******************************************************************************
*************************************************************************** */
/*
**
** Some examples
**
--
-- every sheet and every cell
    select *
    from table( as_read_xlsx.read( as_read_xlsx.file2blob( 'DOC', 'Book1.xlsx' ) ) )
--
-- cell A3 from the first and the second sheet
    select *
    from table( as_read_xlsx.read( as_read_xlsx.file2blob( 'DOC', 'Book1.xlsx' ), '1:2', 'A3' ) )
--
-- every cell from the sheet with the name "Sheet3"
    select *
    from table( as_read_xlsx.read( as_read_xlsx.file2blob( 'DOC', 'Book1.xlsx' ), 'Sheet3' ) )
--
*/
  type tp_one_cell is record
    ( sheet_nr number(2)
    , sheet_name varchar(4000)
    , row_nr number(10)
    , col_nr number(10)
    , cell varchar2(100)
    , cell_type varchar2(1)
    , string_val varchar2(4000)
    , number_val number
    , date_val date
    , formula varchar2(4000)
  );
  type tp_all_cells is table of tp_one_cell;
--
  function read( p_xlsx blob, p_sheets varchar2 := null, p_cell varchar2 := null )
  return tp_all_cells pipelined;
--
  function file2blob
    ( p_dir varchar2
    , p_file_name varchar2
    )
  return blob;
--
end as_read_xlsx;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE package body as_read_xlsx
is
--
  function read( p_xlsx blob, p_sheets varchar2 := null, p_cell varchar2 := null )
  return tp_all_cells pipelined
  is
    t_date1904 boolean;
    type tp_date is table of boolean index by pls_integer;
    t_xf_date tp_date;
    t_numfmt_date tp_date;
    type tp_strings is table of varchar2(32767) index by pls_integer;
    t_strings tp_strings;
    t_sheet_ids tp_strings;
    t_sheet_names tp_strings;
    t_r varchar2(32767);
    t_s varchar2(32767);
    t_val varchar2(32767);
    t_t varchar2(400);
    t_nr number;
    t_c pls_integer;
    t_x pls_integer;
    t_xx pls_integer;
    t_ns varchar2(200) := 'xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"';
    t_nd dbms_xmldom.domnode;
    t_nd2 dbms_xmldom.domnode;
    t_nl dbms_xmldom.domnodelist;
    t_nl2 dbms_xmldom.domnodelist;
    t_nl3 dbms_xmldom.domnodelist;
    t_one_cell tp_one_cell;
--
    function blob2node( p_blob blob )
    return dbms_xmldom.domnode
    is
    begin
      if p_blob is null or dbms_lob.getlength( p_blob ) = 0
      then
        return null;
      end if;
      return dbms_xmldom.makenode( dbms_xmldom.getdocumentelement( dbms_xmldom.newdomdocument( xmltype( p_blob, nls_charset_id( 'AL32UTF8' ) ) ) ) );
    exception
      when others
      then
        declare
          t_nd dbms_xmldom.domnode;
          t_clob         clob;
          t_dest_offset  integer;
          t_src_offset   integer;
          t_lang_context number := dbms_lob.default_lang_ctx;
          t_warning      integer;
        begin
          dbms_lob.createtemporary( t_clob, true );
          t_dest_offset := 1;
          t_src_offset  := 1;
          dbms_lob.converttoclob( t_clob
                                , p_blob
                                , dbms_lob.lobmaxsize
                                , t_dest_offset
                                , t_src_offset
                                , nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8')
                                , t_lang_context
                                , t_warning
                                );
          t_nd := dbms_xmldom.makenode( dbms_xmldom.getdocumentelement( dbms_xmldom.newdomdocument( t_clob ) ) );
          dbms_lob.freetemporary( t_clob );
          return t_nd;
      end;
    end;
--  
    function blob2num( p_blob blob, p_len integer, p_pos integer )
    return number
    is
    begin
      return utl_raw.cast_to_binary_integer( dbms_lob.substr( p_blob, p_len, p_pos ), utl_raw.little_endian );
    end;
--  
    function little_endian( p_big number, p_bytes pls_integer := 4 )
    return raw
    is
    begin
      return utl_raw.substr( utl_raw.cast_from_binary_integer( p_big, utl_raw.little_endian ), 1, p_bytes );
    end;
--  
    function col_alfan( p_col varchar2 )
    return pls_integer
    is
    begin
      return ascii( substr( p_col, -1 ) ) - 64
           + nvl( ( ascii( substr( p_col, -2, 1 ) ) - 64 ) * 26, 0 )
           + nvl( ( ascii( substr( p_col, -3, 1 ) ) - 64 ) * 676, 0 );
    end;
--  
    function get_file
      ( p_zipped_blob blob
      , p_file_name varchar2
      )
    return blob
    is
      t_tmp blob;
      t_ind integer;
      t_hd_ind integer;
      t_fl_ind integer;
      t_encoding varchar2(10);
      t_len integer;
    begin
      t_ind := dbms_lob.getlength( p_zipped_blob ) - 21;
      loop
        exit when t_ind < 1 or dbms_lob.substr( p_zipped_blob, 4, t_ind ) = hextoraw( '504B0506' ); -- End of central directory signature
        t_ind := t_ind - 1;
      end loop;
--  
      if t_ind <= 0
      then
        return null;
      end if;
--  
      t_hd_ind := blob2num( p_zipped_blob, 4, t_ind + 16 ) + 1;
      for i in 1 .. blob2num( p_zipped_blob, 2, t_ind + 8 )
      loop
        if utl_raw.bit_and( dbms_lob.substr( p_zipped_blob, 1, t_hd_ind + 9 ), hextoraw( '08' ) ) = hextoraw( '08' )
        then
          t_encoding := 'AL32UTF8'; -- utf8
        else
          t_encoding := 'US8PC437'; -- IBM codepage 437
        end if;
        if p_file_name = utl_i18n.raw_to_char
                           ( dbms_lob.substr( p_zipped_blob
                                            , blob2num( p_zipped_blob, 2, t_hd_ind + 28 )
                                            , t_hd_ind + 46
                                            )
                           , t_encoding
                           )
        then
          t_len := blob2num( p_zipped_blob, 4, t_hd_ind + 24 ); -- uncompressed length
          if t_len = 0
          then
            if substr( p_file_name, -1 ) in ( '/', '\' )
            then  -- directory/folder
              return null;
            else -- empty file
              return empty_blob();
            end if;
          end if;
--  
          if dbms_lob.substr( p_zipped_blob, 2, t_hd_ind + 10 ) = hextoraw( '0800' ) -- deflate
          then
            t_fl_ind := blob2num( p_zipped_blob, 4, t_hd_ind + 42 );
            t_tmp := hextoraw( '1F8B0800000000000003' ); -- gzip header
            dbms_lob.copy( t_tmp
                         , p_zipped_blob
                         ,  blob2num( p_zipped_blob, 4, t_hd_ind + 20 )
                         , 11
                         , t_fl_ind + 31
                         + blob2num( p_zipped_blob, 2, t_fl_ind + 27 ) -- File name length
                         + blob2num( p_zipped_blob, 2, t_fl_ind + 29 ) -- Extra field length
                         );
            dbms_lob.append( t_tmp, utl_raw.concat( dbms_lob.substr( p_zipped_blob, 4, t_hd_ind + 16 ) -- CRC32
                                                  , little_endian( t_len ) -- uncompressed length
                                                  )
                           );
            return utl_compress.lz_uncompress( t_tmp );
          end if;
--  
          if dbms_lob.substr( p_zipped_blob, 2, t_hd_ind + 10 ) = hextoraw( '0000' ) -- The file is stored (no compression)
          then
            t_fl_ind := blob2num( p_zipped_blob, 4, t_hd_ind + 42 );
            dbms_lob.createtemporary( t_tmp, true );
            dbms_lob.copy( t_tmp
                         , p_zipped_blob
                         , t_len
                         , 1
                         , t_fl_ind + 31
                         + blob2num( p_zipped_blob, 2, t_fl_ind + 27 ) -- File name length
                         + blob2num( p_zipped_blob, 2, t_fl_ind + 29 ) -- Extra field length
                         );
            return t_tmp;
          end if;
        end if;
        t_hd_ind := t_hd_ind + 46
                  + blob2num( p_zipped_blob, 2, t_hd_ind + 28 )  -- File name length
                  + blob2num( p_zipped_blob, 2, t_hd_ind + 30 )  -- Extra field length
                  + blob2num( p_zipped_blob, 2, t_hd_ind + 32 ); -- File comment length
      end loop;
--  
      return null;
    end;
--
  begin
    t_one_cell.cell_type := 'S';
    t_one_cell.sheet_name := 'This doesn''t look like an Excel (xlsx) file to me!';
    t_one_cell.string_val := t_one_cell.sheet_name;
    if dbms_lob.substr( p_xlsx, 4, 1 ) != hextoraw( '504B0304' )
    then
      pipe row( t_one_cell );
      return;
    end if;
    t_nd := blob2node( get_file( p_xlsx, 'xl/workbook.xml' ) );
    if dbms_xmldom.isnull( t_nd )
    then
      pipe row( t_one_cell );
      return;
    end if;
    t_date1904 := lower( dbms_xslprocessor.valueof( t_nd, '/workbook/workbookPr/@date1904', t_ns ) ) in ( 'true', '1' );
    t_nl := dbms_xslprocessor.selectnodes( t_nd, '/workbook/sheets/sheet', t_ns );
    for i in 0 .. dbms_xmldom.getlength( t_nl ) - 1
    loop
      t_sheet_ids( i + 1 ) := dbms_xslprocessor.valueof( dbms_xmldom.item( t_nl, i ), '@r:id', 'xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"' );
      t_sheet_names( i + 1 ) := dbms_xslprocessor.valueof( dbms_xmldom.item( t_nl, i ), '@name' );
    end loop;
    t_nd := blob2node( get_file( p_xlsx, 'xl/styles.xml' ) );
    t_nl := dbms_xslprocessor.selectnodes( t_nd, '/styleSheet/numFmts/numFmt', t_ns );
    for i in 0 .. dbms_xmldom.getlength( t_nl ) - 1
    loop
      t_val := dbms_xslprocessor.valueof( dbms_xmldom.item( t_nl, i ), '@formatCode' );
      if (  instr( t_val, 'dd' ) > 0
         or instr( t_val, 'mm' ) > 0
         or instr( t_val, 'yy' ) > 0
         )
      then
        t_numfmt_date( dbms_xslprocessor.valueof( dbms_xmldom.item( t_nl, i ), '@numFmtId' ) ) := true;
      end if;
    end loop;
    t_numfmt_date( 14 ) := true;
    t_numfmt_date( 15 ) := true;
    t_numfmt_date( 16 ) := true;
    t_numfmt_date( 17 ) := true;
    t_numfmt_date( 22 ) := true;
    t_nl := dbms_xslprocessor.selectnodes( t_nd, '/styleSheet/cellXfs/xf/@numFmtId', t_ns );
    for i in 0 .. dbms_xmldom.getlength( t_nl ) - 1
    loop
      t_xf_date( i ) := t_numfmt_date.exists( dbms_xmldom.getnodevalue( dbms_xmldom.item( t_nl, i ) ) );
    end loop;
    t_nd := blob2node( get_file( p_xlsx, 'xl/sharedStrings.xml' ) );
    if not dbms_xmldom.isnull( t_nd )
    then
      t_x := 0;
      t_xx := 5000;
      loop
        t_nl := dbms_xslprocessor.selectnodes( t_nd, '/sst/si[position()>="' || to_char( t_x * t_xx + 1 ) || '" and position()<=" ' || to_char( ( t_x + 1 ) * t_xx ) || '"]', t_ns );
        exit when dbms_xmldom.getlength( t_nl ) = 0;
        t_x := t_x + 1;
        for i in 0 .. dbms_xmldom.getlength( t_nl ) - 1
        loop
          t_c := t_strings.count;
          t_strings( t_c ) := dbms_xslprocessor.valueof( dbms_xmldom.item( t_nl, i ), '.' );
          if t_strings( t_c ) is null
          then 
            t_strings( t_c ) := dbms_xslprocessor.valueof( dbms_xmldom.item( t_nl, i ), '*/text()' );
            if t_strings( t_c ) is null
            then 
              t_nl2 := dbms_xslprocessor.selectnodes( dbms_xmldom.item( t_nl, i ), 'r/t/text()' );
              for j in 0 .. dbms_xmldom.getlength( t_nl2 ) - 1
              loop
                t_strings( t_c ) := t_strings( t_c ) || dbms_xmldom.getnodevalue( dbms_xmldom.item( t_nl2, j ) );
              end loop;
            end if;
          end if;
        end loop;
      end loop;
    end if;
    t_nd2 := blob2node( get_file( p_xlsx, 'xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels' ) );
    for i in 1 .. t_sheet_ids.count
    loop
      if ( p_sheets is null
         or instr( ':' || p_sheets || ':', ':' || to_char( i ) || ':' ) > 0
         or instr( ':' || p_sheets || ':', ':' || t_sheet_names( i ) || ':' ) > 0
         )
      then
        t_val := dbms_xslprocessor.valueof( t_nd2, '/Relationships/Relationship[@Id="' || t_sheet_ids( i ) || '"]/@Target', 'xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"' );
        t_one_cell.sheet_nr := i;
        t_one_cell.sheet_name := t_sheet_names( i );
        t_nd := blob2node( get_file( p_xlsx, 'xl/' || t_val ) );
        t_nl3 := dbms_xslprocessor.selectnodes( t_nd, '/worksheet/sheetData/row' );
        for r in 0 .. dbms_xmldom.getlength( t_nl3 ) - 1
        loop
          t_nl2 := dbms_xslprocessor.selectnodes( dbms_xmldom.item( t_nl3, r ), 'c' );
          for j in 0 .. dbms_xmldom.getlength( t_nl2 ) - 1
          loop
            t_one_cell.date_val := null;
            t_one_cell.number_val := null;
            t_one_cell.string_val := null;
            t_r := dbms_xslprocessor.valueof( dbms_xmldom.item( t_nl2, j ), '@r', t_ns );
            t_val := dbms_xslprocessor.valueof( dbms_xmldom.item( t_nl2, j ), 'v' );
            -- see Changelog 2013-02-19 formula column 
            t_one_cell.formula := dbms_xslprocessor.valueof( dbms_xmldom.item( t_nl2, j ), 'f' );
            -- see Changelog 2013-02-18 type='str' 
            t_t := dbms_xslprocessor.valueof( dbms_xmldom.item( t_nl2, j ), '@t' );
            if t_t in ( 'str', 'inlineStr', 'e' )
            then
              t_one_cell.cell_type := 'S';
              t_one_cell.string_val := t_val;
            elsif t_t = 's'
            then
              t_one_cell.cell_type := 'S';
              if t_val is not null
              then
                t_one_cell.string_val := t_strings( to_number( t_val ) );
              end if;
            else
              t_s := dbms_xslprocessor.valueof( dbms_xmldom.item( t_nl2, j ), '@s' );
              t_nr := to_number( t_val
                               , case when instr( t_val, 'E' ) = 0
                                   then translate( t_val, '.012345678,-+', 'D999999999' )
                                   else translate( substr( t_val, 1, instr( t_val, 'E' ) - 1 ), '.012345678,-+', 'D999999999' ) || 'EEEE'
                                 end
                               , 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=.,'
                               );
              if t_s is not null and t_xf_date( to_number( t_s ) )
              then
                t_one_cell.cell_type := 'D';
                if t_date1904
                then
                  t_one_cell.date_val := to_date('01-01-1904','DD-MM-YYYY') + to_number( t_nr );
                else
                  t_one_cell.date_val := to_date('01-03-1900','DD-MM-YYYY') + ( to_number( t_nr ) - 61 );
                end if;
              else
                t_one_cell.cell_type := 'N';
                t_nr := round( t_nr, 14 - substr( to_char( t_nr, 'TME' ), -3 ) );
                t_one_cell.number_val := t_nr;
              end if;
            end if;
            t_one_cell.row_nr := ltrim( t_r, rtrim( t_r, '0123456789' ) );
            t_one_cell.col_nr := col_alfan( rtrim( t_r, '0123456789' ) );
            t_one_cell.cell := t_r;
            if p_cell is null or t_r = upper( p_cell )
            then
              pipe row( t_one_cell );
            end if;
          end loop;
        end loop;
      end if;
    end loop;
    return;
  end;
--
  function file2blob
    ( p_dir varchar2
    , p_file_name varchar2
    )
  return blob
  is
    file_lob bfile;
    file_blob blob;
  begin
    file_lob := bfilename( p_dir, p_file_name );
    dbms_lob.open( file_lob, dbms_lob.file_readonly );
    dbms_lob.createtemporary( file_blob, true );
    dbms_lob.loadfromfile( file_blob, file_lob, dbms_lob.lobmaxsize );
    dbms_lob.close( file_lob );
    return file_blob;
  exception
    when others then
      if dbms_lob.isopen( file_lob ) = 1
      then
        dbms_lob.close( file_lob );
      end if;
      if dbms_lob.istemporary( file_blob ) = 1
      then
        dbms_lob.freetemporary( file_blob );
      end if;
      raise;
  end;
--
END as_read_xlsx;
/
```