# How to fetch bulk data in oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

There is one table named PROFIT which contain all the profit data for a company. This table contain more than 5 million data.The table structure is like below

```
COMPANYID   YEAR    PROFIT
   100001   2017     50000
   100001   2016     30000
   100001   2015     20000
   100002   2017     80000
   100002   2016     70000
   100002   2015     40000
   100003   2016    100000
   100003   2015     75000
   100004   2017     50000
   100004   2016     40000
   100004   2015     30000
   100004   2014     10000
   100004   2013      5000
```

I have an Excel list of 75000 `companyid` and I need to fetch data for all those companies. I can't use `IN` because it allow` only 999 values in a list at a time.

Please help me. How can I fetch all those record using single query? Currently I am using Oracle 11g.

Comment: In your previous question, you said you could Load your excel  data through `sqlloader`. Why can't you do the same here? Once you load it into another temp table, you could do a `select *... in ( select  from your_temp_table`

Comment: Previously I worked in Dev environment but in this case it's production. I have only read access. :(

Comment: Here you can use this answer from TYPO on stack. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33182037/how-to-read-a-excel-file-and-insert-data-into-oracle-table)

Comment: There is very little we could help if that's the case. You have to probably ask the concerned admin to create the table in production for temporary purpose for you and let you run a query, or maybe create a database link from Prod to DEV and connect the dev table from Prod using the  db link. External table requires you to create a directory, which seems unlikely in your case.

Comment: Create table in Oracle SQL developer with the same structure as your file. Load your Excel data into that table. You may create table constraints and/or indexes if necessary. Use simple select from newly created table insert into your destination table, or merge, or PL/SQL Bulk Collect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming ...

- you just want to run a SQL statement
- the spreadsheet is simply a list of IDs

... you can prepare a script like this.

1. Save Excel spreadsheet as `.csv`
2. Open `.csv` file in a text editor which supports regex
3. Use regex patterns to turn each number into a select statement: `select \1 as co_id from dual union all`
4. Top and tail the output to create a `with` clause subquery
5. Join that to your PROFIT table

So now you have something like this:

```
with cte as (
    select 1 as co_id from dual union all
    select 2 as co_id from dual union all
    ....
    select 75000 as co_id from dual 
) 
select p.companyid
       , p.year
       , sum(p.profit) as annual_profit -- or whatever
from cte
     join profit p
       on cte.co_id = p.companyid
group by p.companyid
         , p.year
```

This is not a dynamic solution but a static script should be okay for a one-off exercise. If this is to be a regular report you should negotiate the right to make changes in Production so you can support a better approach.

Comment: Thank you very much. I checked with small amount of data and it's working. Yes this is not a regular report. I get those type of requirement in a monthly basis. Most of the time i get for for two thousand or three thousand record. So Most of the time I use "IN" operator and run the query several time.But this time record count was big. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can run the PL/SQL code in your production environment. Then you can try the below code, which accepts up to 4GB of string and returns in form of rows after applying splitter.

As you have the rows in excel, so you can copy all the rows with post suffix a "," and then delete the new line so it becomes your input parameter. And pass all these values in single quota or string delimiter as  I passed in below example code.

Then you can pass on your table for IN clause as I passed here in "test_2", an dummy table.

```
declare
v_input_str clob := '100002,100003,100004,100005,100006,100007,100008,100009,100010,100011,100012,100013,100014,100015,100016,100017,100018,100019,100020,100021,100022,100023,100024,100025,100026,100027,100028,100029,100030,100031,100032,100033,100034,100035,100036,100037,100038,100039,100040,100041,100042,100043,100044,100045,100046,100047,100048,100049,100050,100051,100052,100053,100054,100055,100056,100057,100058,100059,100060,100061,100062,100063,100064,100065,100066,100067,100068,100069,100070,100071,100072,100073,100074,100075,100076,100077,100078,100079,100080,100081,100082,100083,100084,100085,100086,100087,100088,100089,100090,100091,100092,100093,100094,100095,100096,100097,100098,100099,100100,100101,100102,100103,100104,100105,100106,100107,100108,100109,100110,100111,100112,100113,100114,100115,100116,100117,100118,100119,100120,100121,100122,100123,100124,100125,100126,100127,100128,100129,100130,100131,100132,100133,100134,100135,100136,100137,100138,100139,100140,100141,100142,100143,100144,100145,100146,100147,100148,100149,100150,100151,100152,100153,100154,100155,100156,100157,100158,100159,100160,100161,100162,100163,100164,100165,100166,100167,100168,100169,100170,100171,100172,100173,100174,100175,100176,100177,100178,100179,100180,100181,100182,100183,100184,100185,100186,100187,100188,100189,100190,100191,100192,100193,100194,100195,100196,100197,100198,100199,100200,100201,100202,100203,100204,100205,100206,100207,100208,100209,100210,100211,100212,100213,100214,100215,100216,100217,100218,100219,100220,100221,100222,100223,100224,100225,100226,100227,100228,100229,100230,100231,100232,100233,100234,100235,100236,100237,100238,100239,100240,100241,100242,100243,100244,100245,100246,100247,100248,100249,100250,100251,100252,100253,100254,100255,100256,100257,100258,100259,100260,100261,100262,100263,100264,100265,100266,100267,100268,100269,100270,100271,100272,100273,100274,100275,100276,100277,100278,100279,100280,100281,100282,100283,100284,100285,100286,100287,100288,100289,100290,100291,100292,100293,100294,100295,100296,100297,100298,100299,100300,100301,100302,100303,100304,100305,100306,100307,100308,100309,100310,100311,100312,100313,100314,100315,100316,100317,100318,100319,100320,100321,100322,100323,100324,100325,100326,100327,100328,100329,100330,100331,100332,100333,100334,100335,100336,100337,100338,100339,100340,100341,100342,100343,100344,100345,100346,100347,100348,100349,100350,100351,100352,100353,100354,100355,100356,100357,100358,100359,100360,100361,100362,100363,100364,100365,100366,100367,100368,100369,100370,100371,100372,100373,100374,100375,100376,100377,100378,100379,100380,100381,100382,100383,100384,100385,100386,100387,100388,100389,100390,100391,100392,100393,100394,100395,100396,100397,100398,100399,100400,100401,100402,100403,100404,100405,100406,100407,100408,100409,100410,100411,100412,100413,100414,100415,100416,100417,100418,100419,100420,100421,100422,100423,100424,100425,100426,100427,100428,100429,100430,100431,100432,100433,100434,100435,100436,100437,100438,100439,100440,100441,100442,100443,100444,100445,100446,100447,100448,100449,100450,100451,100452,100453,100454,100455,100456,100457,100458,100459,100460,100461,100462,100463,100464,100465,100466,100467,100468,100469,100470,100471,100472,100473,100474,100475,100476,100477,100478,100479,100480,100481,100482,100483,100484,100485,100486,100487,100488,100489,100490,100491,100492,100493,100494,100495,100496,100497,100498,100499,100500,100501,100502,100503,100504,100505,100506,100507,100508,100509,100510,100511,100512,100513,100514,100515,100516,100517,100518,100519,100520,100521,100522,100523,100524,100525,100526,100527,100528,100529,100530,100531,100532,100533,100534,100535,100536,100537,100538,100539,100540,100541,100542,100543,100544,100545,100546,100547,100548,100549,100550,100551,100552,100553,100554,100555,100556,100557,100558,100559,100560,100561,100562,100563,100564,100565,100566,100567,100568,100569,100570,100571,100572,100573';
v_count number;
begin

select count(1) into v_count
from test_2 
where id in (with i as (select v_input_str as str from dual)
                select to_number(regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, level)) in_clause_values
                from i connect by level <= length(regexp_replace(str, '[^,]+')) + 1
            );

dbms_output.put_line('No of elements : '||v_count);

end;
```

Comment: Removing the WITH clause as it's not more required,            
select count(1) into v_count
from test_2 
where id in (select to_number(regexp_substr(v_input_str, '[^,]+', 1, level)) in_clause_values
                from dual connect by level <= length(regexp_replace(v_input_str, '[^,]+')) + 1
            );