# Excel UTL_FILE.GET_LINE result encoded

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, plsql-package

I'm trying to build a package with a procedure which takes .XLSX file, parse and insert to a table in database.

What I have achieved so far is the code below:

```
create or replace package body pkg_name
is
    procedure fetch_and_insert_data
    is
        l_display   varchar2(32767);
        l_id        varchar2(32767);
        l_filename  varchar2(100)    := 'my_file.xlsx';

        v_file      UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE; 
    begin        
      execute immediate 'create or replace directory XOBJ as ''' || c_file_dir || '''';
      v_file := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(location     => 'XOBJ', 
                               filename     => l_filename, 
                               open_mode    => 'r', 
                               max_linesize => 32767);

      loop
         begin
            UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(v_file,l_id);
            dbms_output.put_line(l_id);
            EXCEPTION
              WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            EXIT;
         end;
      end loop;

      UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_file); 

      EXCEPTION 
      WHEN OTHERS THEN 
        UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_file); 
      RAISE; 

    end fetch_and_insert_data;
end;
```

But when I run it it's encoded .

> PK!bîha[Content_Types].xml ¢(
>   ¬”MOÃ0†ïHü‡*WÔfã€Z·G˜Äø¡q×hiÅÞØþ=nö!„Ê¦‰]µ±ß÷‰kg4Y·6[ADã])†Å@dà*¯›—âcö’ß‹I9­¬wPŠ

How can I decode and maintain my line as it is in XLSX file? Tried with CSV file and works perfectly but i need to use XLSX files.

Also tried other external packages found online and didn't helped.

Comment: An XLSX file is a zipped set of XML files, it isn't plain text. What external packages did you look at, and what was wrong with them? [This might be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33212086/266304) if you haven't already looked it.

Comment: Indeed, i know this but it there any way to parse it correctly with UTL_FILE ?

Comment: UTL_FILE is not a parser, it is a file reader. An XLSX is an XML file compressed with ZIP. To parse XLSX in PL/SQL I've used the code from this blog with good results: https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/easy-xlsx-parser:-just-with-sql-and-plsql